# Split tag xml in more file xml

Tags: xml, tags

I have one file xml with one header and n body

```
<Header>
   <B>
     <C></C>
     <D></D>
   </B>
</Header>
<Body>
   <F></F>
</Body>
<Body>
   <G></G>
</Body>
<Body>
   <H></H>
</Body>
```

I must create n new file xml with `<Header>` and one `<Body>`
For example:

First.xml

```
<Header>
   <B>
     <C></C>
     <D></D>
   </B>
</Header>
<Body>
   <F></F>
</Body>
```

Second.xml

```
<Header>
   <B>
     <C></C>
     <D></D>
   </B>
</Header>
<Body>
   <G></G>
</Body>
```

Third.xml

```
<Header>
   <B>
     <C></C>
     <D></D>
   </B>
</Header>
<Body>
   <H></H>
</Body>
```

Initially I tried to create new n documents equal to the original. 
After I take First.xml and I keep the first block Body and delete the other Body 
With Second.xml I keep the second block of the Body and delete the other 
I also accept any other suggestion.

Comment: Show your effort, post the code you have tried so far. And what programming language you're using?

Comment: post the correct XML file format for this it will generate an error "There are multiple root elements".